# Non-exported virtual function results in LNK2001 in derived classes in other projects

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, linker-errors

I discovered this little gotcha with virtual functions and DLLs, and thought I would share what I learned about it.

Let's say that you have two projects, called `Alpha` and `Bravo`. `Alpha` is built as a DLL, to which `Bravo` references. Now, in `Alpha`, you have the base class:

Header file: (Alpha.h)

```
#pragma once

#if defined(EXPORT_ALPHA)
#define ALPHA_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ALPHA_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class BaseClass
{
public:
  ALPHA_API BaseClass();
  ALPHA_API virtual ~BaseClass();

  virtual void Foo();
};
```

Cpp file: (Alpha.cpp)

```
#include "Alpha.h"
#include <cstdio>

BaseClass::BaseClass() {}
BaseClass::~BaseClass() {}
void BaseClass::Foo()
{
  printf( "Foo\n" );
}
```

Then, in `Bravo`, you have the derived class and main (call it main.cpp):

```
#include "Alpha.h"
#include <cstdio>

class DerivedClass : public BaseClass
{
public:
  DerivedClass() : BaseClass() {}
  virtual ~DerivedClass() {}
};

int main()
{
  DerivedClass* derived = new DerivedClass();
  printf( "Created instance of derived class.\n" );
  delete derived;
  return 0;
}
```

Now, `Alpha` builds successfully, generates its DLL, and goes on its merry way. But then, you go to build `Bravo`, and you get `LNK2001 - unresolved external symbol BaseClass::Foo()`, even if you never actually use it.

So, what is happening? Why is it generating a linker error if we never call `Foo()`?

Comment: The constructor is inline. Try removing the inline definition of the constructor, and explicitly defining the constructor in a translation unit that gets linked into the DLL. Looks to me like because the constructor is defined inline, when Bravo gets compiled it tries to build the base class, so it needs a reference to the base virtual method. Although this seems like it should still work, the the virtual base method is also inline.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, but the compiler/linker is not required to inline it, even if you add the inline keyword. Plus, the functions are inline-able only because I wrote them short enought to use as an example that wasn't cluttered with extra code.

Comment: I see no option for the compiler ***not*** to inline everything. When the translation unit includes this header file, the compiler has no means to determine if some other translation unit will also see the same class declaration, and, as such, emit the constructor, and the virtual method, since it's needed to construct the virtual dispatch table. So it seems to me that the compiler must inline everything when compiling "Bravo" (here, "inline" means emitting the function's code as part of the translation unit, not actual inlining at some call point).

Comment: Alright, well, I updated it for the sake of correctness. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Comment: Wait, are you saying that the shown code does not actually reproduce the compilation error, and is merely representative of whatever the actual failing code is? If so, this would be ground for closing this question due to a failure to provide a [mcve]. Simply "paraphrasing" the problematic code is not sufficient.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik as of my last edit, it generates the linker error as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to how the virtual table is populated by the linker. When you are linking `Alpha`, it has both the declaration of the virtual function, and since it knows where the assembled code for `Foo()` is, it just populates the BaseClass's virtual table with the address of the assembled code. But, since `Foo()` is not exported, it doesn't add an entry for the function to the corresponding lib. So, for instance, if a DLL and static lib were compiled with comments, they might look something like this:

Alpha.dll:

```
# this is BaseClass's virtual table, located at some random address only known internally
0x00002000 # Function address of ~BaseClass()
0x00004000 # Function address of Foo()

# This is the machine code for Foo(), located at address 0x00004000
mov eax, [ebx]
add eax, ecx
...
```

Alpha.lib:

```
# Exports:
BaseClass()@BaseClass  : 0x00001000 # Address in the DLL of the constructor
~BaseClass()@BaseClass : 0x00002000 # Address in the DLL of the destructor
```

When it goes to link `Bravo`, it knows that it needs to add an entry for `Foo()` to DerivedClass's virtual table. (It knows because the compiler told it when it read the included headers.) So, first, the linker looks for a compiled function called `Foo()@DerivedClass`. There isn't one, so then it looks for a compiled function called `Foo()@BaseClass`. However, the static lib does not have an entry for `Foo()@BaseClass`, because `Alpha` did not export it. Thus, the linker doesn't find any entries for `Foo()@BaseClass`, and therefore cannot populate DerivedClass's virtual table with a function address for `Foo()`.

This means that you will get the linker error in the downstream project. It also means that if `DerivedClass` provides an implementation for `Foo()`, this linker error will not occur unless that implementation attempts to call the base class's implementation. However, the right way to fix this is to make sure you export all virtual functions in a class that might have derived classes in downstream projects (either that, or export the class itself).

Comment: If DerivedClass implements Foo(), you will still need a reference to BaseClass::Foo to be used as part of construction and destruction.

Comment: @RaymondChen Actually, no you don't. (Try adding an implementation for Foo() to derived class - it'll build just fine.) The virtual table is populated at link-time, and if the derived class has an implementation for Foo(), then it doesn't need to bother looking for the base class's Foo(), because it has the address of the implementation it needs. All the constructor does is set the vptr to the address of the virtual table for the class being instantiated.

Comment: My mistake. I thought the vtable swap happened inside Derived's destructor, which means that Derived needs to be able to access BaseClass's vtable. But the swap actually happens at the start of BaseClass's destructor.